# Resolvent convergence with only zero intersection of domains?

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, unbounded-operators

Let $ X $ be a Hilbert space. Can we find unbounded self-adjoint operators $ A,  A_n $  on $ X $ such that $ A_n \stackrel{s.r.s}{\longrightarrow} A, $ that is, 
\begin{equation*}
\ R_\lambda(A_n) \stackrel{s}{\longrightarrow} R_\lambda(A), \ \forall\  \lambda \in \mathbb{C}\setminus \mathbb{R}, \ \ \text{where} \ R_\lambda(A) := (\lambda I -A)^{-1}
\end{equation*} 
but $ (\bigcap_{n \in \mathbb{N} } \mathcal{D}(A_n)) \bigcap \mathcal{D}(A) = \{ 0 \} $?

**Edit:** This question is equivalent to [Convergence of (unbounded) self-adjoint operators](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2971322/convergence-of-unbounded-self-adjoint-operators)

Comment: It may not be the most interesting example, but you can simply take self-adjoint operators $S,T$ whose domains have trivial intersection and set $A_1=S$, $A_2=A_3=\dots=T$ (only a comment because I can't give a construction of such operators $S$, $T$, but it's well known that they exist).

Comment: @MaoWao Thank you for your comment! This is a result i am eager for, so could you please indicate where can i find the construction?

Comment: Apparently the result can be found in Von Neumann. *Zur Theorie der Unbeschränkten Matrizen* and Diximier. *Étude sur les variétés et les opérateurs de Julia, avec quelques applications*. But right now I don't have access to the former article and can't find it in the latter.

Comment: @MaoWao Thank you for your indication! I find the former article in (https://gdz.sub.uni-goettingen.de/id/PPN243919689_0161?tify=%7B%22view%22:%22info%22,%22pages%22:%5B212%5D%7D) . However, the content is purely Germany. Could you help look and explain the construction if possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let 
$$
D(S)=\left\lbrace f\in L^2(\mathbb{R})\mid \int (e^{x^2}f(x))^2\,dx<\infty\right\rbrace,\,Sf(x)=e^{x^2}f(x)\\
D(T)=\{f\in L^2(\mathbb{R})\mid \hat f\in D(S)\},\,Tf=\mathcal{F}^{-1}(S\hat f).$$

In particular, if $f\in D(S)\cap D(T)$, then $e^{|\cdot|^2/2}f, e^{|\cdot|^2/2}\hat f\in S'(\mathbb{R})$. It follows from Hardy's incertainty principle* that $f(x)=e^{-|x|^2/2}p(x)$ for some polynomial $p$. Using once again $f\in D(S)$, we see that $f$ must be zero.

Now you can take $A_1=S$ and $A_n=T$ for $n>1$. Clearly $A_n\to T$ and $\bigcap_n D(A_n)\cap D(T)=D(S)\cap D(T)=\{0\}$.

*Depending on you definition of the Fourier transform, you may need different factors in the exponentials.

Comment: Figuring out $ \mathcal{R}(S+/- iI) = L^2 $ for symmetric $ S $  gives the self-adjointness of $ S $. How can we prove that $ T $ is self-adjoint?

Comment: It's unitarily equivalent to a self-adjoint operator. In general $(UAU^\ast)^\ast=U A^\ast U$ for densely defined $A$ and unitary $U$ (this can be verified directly from the definitions).

Comment: @ MaoWao Deeply thank you for your efforts in explaining the construction! Now i can handle the line of construction (in this answer) but the examination of proof for Hardy's uncertainty principle. I will accept this answer when i can  check the latter out (I am not familiar with the analysis in complex plane and Schwartz spaces) and beg your pardon for my possible delay.

Comment: Recently I am really busy and spare no time to examine the proof for Hardy's uncertainty principle. But i think the example should be accepted with no more delay. Now i accept the answer. Sorry for not keeping my word.